# Найти корневые вершины, через которые проходит наибольшее количество путей максимальных путей

Tags: c++, алгоритм, рекурсия, бинарное-дерево

### Найти корневые вершины, через которые проходит наибольшее количество путей максимальных путей.

Путь в дереве — это путь между двумя вершинами дерева (допускается что вершины совпадают). Например, для дерева

```
                                                 20
                                              /       \
                                           10       30
                                         /     \
                                       5       15
                                               /    \
                                            12     17
```

путь между вершинами 15 и 20 это 15-10-20, путь между вершинами 5 и 15 это 5-10-15, путь между вершинами 5 и 5 это 5.

Максимальный путь — это путь, который нельзя расширить. Например путь  5-10-15 не является максимальным, поскольку его можно расширить, например, до 5-10-15-12 (путь 5-10-15-12 включает путь 5-10-15). Путь 5-10-15-12 уже будет максимальным, поскольку его нельзя расширить (т.е. не существует никакого другого пути, который включает  путь 5-10-15-12). Нетрудно понять, что максимальный путь — это путь между листьями ( за некоторым исключением). Например, если бы в приведенном выше дереве не было вершины 30, то путь 12-15-10-20 был бы максимальным, но 20 это не лист.
Каждый максимальный путь имеет корневую вершину. Например, для пути 5-10-15-12 корневой будет вершина 10.
Для дерева без вершины 30 вершина 20 максимального пути 12-15-10-20 будет корневой.

Может ли кто-то предложить алгоритм решения данной задачи?(с некоторыми поправками выше)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Заметим, что если путь максимальной длинны, имеет крневую вершину (i), то можно разбить этот путь на две части (возможно, одна половина нулевой длинны), причем обе части будут движением строго вниз по дереву, от  вершины (i).

На первом этапе, обойдем дерево от собирая в каждом узле следующею информацию: (a) Какова максимальная длинна пути, при движении от этой вершины строго вниз. (b) Сколько существует путей длинны a (при движении из заданной вершины строго вниз).

Для листев (i):

```
a(i)=0, 
b(i)=1
```

Для вершин (i) имеющщих одну дочернию вершину (j):

```
a(i)=a(j)+1
b(i)=b(j)
```

Для вершин (i) имеющщих две дочерних вершины (j), (k):

```
a(i)=max(a(j),a(k))+1
b(i)= (a(j)==a(k)) ? (b(j)+b(k)) : (a(j)<a(k)) ? b(k) : b(j)
```

Число путей, проходящий через вершину (i), как через корневую вершину равно: `c(i)=b(j)*b(k)`, если дочерних вершин две, или `c(i)=b(j)` - если одна.

Таким образом, задача решается за два обхода дерева: (1) вычисление a,b; (2) вычисление с, и сбор списка вершин, для которых он маскимален.

Затраты времени: O(n), где n - число вершин.